# Return variables from mock(php)

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I want test some variable inside function, but this function don't return it.

I have function like this:

```
<?php

class Test 
{

   private $repo;       

   public function __construct($repo)
   {
        $this->repo = $repo;
   }

   public function exemple()
   {
        $name = 'Example name';
        $this->repo->add($name);
   }

}
```

And test like this:

```
<?php

use Mockery as M;

class someTest extends TestCase
{
   public testConstract()
   {
       $repo = M::mock(SomeClass::class);
       $repo->shouldReceive('add');
       $test = new Test($repo);
       $test->exemple();
   }
}
```

How I can test variable `$name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the withArgs directive as [described in the doc](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html?highlight=withargs#expectation-declarations).
As Example, you can modify your test as follow:

```
<?php

use Mockery as M;

class someTest extends TestCase
{
   public testConstract()
   {
       $repo = M::mock(SomeClass::class);
       $repo->shouldReceive('add')->withArgs(array('Example name'));
       $test = new Test($repo);
       $test->exemple();
   }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you! But I mean how can I assertEquals('Example name', $name)?

Comment: Hi @Iwan the assertion is implicit in the definition of the expectation. You can try with a wrong arg message (As example: `->withArgs(array('wrong input'));`

Comment: Ok, thank you. But if I have to test variable, I think I can just `return $name`?

Comment: @Iwan depends on the scenario, probably you need to pass the variable to the tested method instead of have inside itself. If the variable depends on other called method you can isolate the test and mock the other call. Hope this help